# Compare array between interval SQL

Tags: postgresql, between

I have an array which has 3 dates : 2014-11-20 2014-11-25 2014-11-30

and I need to compare if those date are between 2014-11-01 AND 2014-11-30

I am trying to unnest the array and then compare between those dates but it is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

HERE you are a working example, tested on postgresql 9.3:

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['20141120', '20141125', '20141130']::date[]) AS mycolumn
WHERE mycolumn > '20141101'
AND mycolumn < '20141130';
```

Comment: > and < is not the same as BETWEEN, you need >= and <= or just BETWEEN

Comment: What do you need to join?